# I'm trying to access a query list of child directive from a parent directive in the after view init method but the querylist remains undefined

Tags: angular, directive, viewchildren

`QueryList` of child directives remains undefined in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

What i'm I missing?
Here my code:

`app.component.html`

```
<main appDirOne>
  <p appDirTwo>Main content</p>
  <p appDirTwo>Main content</p>
  <p appDirTwo>Main content</p>
  <p appDirTwo>Main content</p>
</main>
```

child directive
`dir-two.directive.ts`

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirTwo]'
})
export class DirTwoDirective {

  constructor() { 
    console.log(Math.random())
  }

}
```

parent directive
`dir-one.directive.ts`

```
    import {
      AfterViewInit,
      Directive,
      QueryList,
      ViewChildren,
    } from '@angular/core';
    import { DirTwoDirective } from './dir-two.directive';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appDirOne]',
    })
    export class DirOneDirective implements AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChildren(DirTwoDirective) childDirectives: QueryList<DirTwoDirective>;
      constructor() {}
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.childDirectives); // <--- still undefined here
      }
    }
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m3mipg)

Answer (score 1):

Directives do not have a view, so you cannot use `@ViewChild` / `@ViewChildren`.

In your case however you could use `@ContentChildren`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirOne]',
})
export class DirOneDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChildren(DirTwoDirective) childDirectives: QueryList<DirTwoDirective>;
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.childDirectives); // <--- should be there now ;)
  }
}
```

[Updated blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujt5wh)